# xampp apache rewrite not working

Tags: apache, laravel, mod-rewrite

I have a folder called crm in htdocs which contains a fresh laravel 5.1
project and i am trying to acess it via http://localhost/crm/
but it just brings the index of page containing the directory contents
instead of the page mapped in my routes.php as

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('panel');
});
```

i have checked that apache mod_rewrite is enable in httpd.conf

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so

DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs">

    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI

    AllowOverride All

    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

then the .htaccess file in crm/public folder contains

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I have also tried to change it to

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to point Laravel to `public` directory to make it work. For example, if you've installed Laravel in `C:/xampp/htdocs/` directory, you need to use these settings:

```
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/public"
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/public">
```

Do not edit `.htacces` inside public folder. Try to change settings and load Laravel website by going to `localhost` first.

When you've edited Apache config file, you should restart web server.

Comment: I did that but now am having problems with assets (css & js) not loading unless i move them to the public folder. should i do that or is there another way around?

Comment: CSS and JS should only be located in a `public` folder. That's how Laravel works.