# Laravel 5.2.31: routing: 404 not found error message

Tags: laravel

Using Laravel Framework version 5.2.31 and Apache/2.4.12 (Ubuntu) Server. Got following error message:

> 404 Not Found The requested URL /laravel/public/signup was not found on this server.

Thank you for any help.

Below is routes.php (That file is no longer accurate. See new one below in Edit section)

```
<?php

Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function() 
{
    Route::get('/', function () 
    {
        return view('welcome');
    });
    Route::post('/signup', [
        'uses' => 'UserController@postSignUp',
        'as' => 'signup'
    ]);
});
```

Below is UserController.php file

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function postSignUp(Request $Request)
    {
        $email = $request['email'];
        $prenom = $request['prenom'];
        $motDePasse = bcrypt($request['motDePasse']);

        $user = new User();
        $user->email = $email;
        $user->prenom = $prenom;
        $user->motDePasse = $motDePasse;

        $user->save();

        return redirect()->back();
    }

    public function postSignIn(Request $Request)
    {

    }
}
```

**Edit**

Below is routes.php

```
<?php

Route::get('/', function () 
{
    return view('welcome');
});
Route::post('/signup', [
    'uses' => 'UserController@postSignUp',
    'as' => 'signup'
]);
```

Below is RouteServiceProvider.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Routing\Router;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\RouteServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;

class RouteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * This namespace is applied to your controller routes.
     *
     * In addition, it is set as the URL generator's root namespace.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';

    /**
     * Define your route model bindings, pattern filters, etc.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Routing\Router  $router
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot(Router $router)
    {
        //

        parent::boot($router);
    }

    /**
     * Define the routes for the application.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Routing\Router  $router
     * @return void
     */
    public function map(Router $router)
    {
        $this->mapWebRoutes($router);

        //
    }

    /**
     * Define the "web" routes for the application.
     *
     * These routes all receive session state, CSRF protection, etc.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Routing\Router  $router
     * @return void
     */
    protected function mapWebRoutes(Router $router)
    {
        $router->group([
            'namespace' => $this->namespace, 'middleware' => 'web',
        ], function ($router) {
            require app_path('Http/routes.php');
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, it seems like you're using `post` method in `routes.php`, but you're trying to load the route using `get` method.

Second this is you have wrong web server configuration. Web server [should be pointed to a `public` directory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35843846/1227923) of you Laravel project (you should create VirtualHost for it and restart web server).

Also, remove `web` middleware from `routes.php`, becuase [it will cause errors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36784408/1227923).

Comment: I've edited file `route.php` according the links you have provided. I checked file `RouteServiceProvider.php` on my server; its content is the same as the one one here [link]https://github.com/laravel/laravel/commit/5c30c98db96459b4cc878d085490e4677b0b67ed#diff-b467cc786635bd6945b17726282f1c64[/link] The error message `404 page not found` still showing.

Comment: Did you do other two things from my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

And change paths for :

open local/bootstrap/paths.php

```
'public' => __DIR__.'/../public', to 'public' => __DIR__.'/../../',
```

open local/bootstrap/paths.php and find below code

'public' => **DIR**.'/../public',
change with below code

'public' => **DIR**.'/../../',

```
Open index.php (on root) and find below code

require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/start.php';
```

change with below code

```
require __DIR__.'/local/bootstrap/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/local/bootstrap/start.php';
```

Now you have all set you can access url http://example.com/ if still problem try with clear cache of browser.

Comment: I'm using Apache/2.4.12. That line is already uncommented in `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled` as `LoadModule rewrite_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_rewrite.so`