# Using Laravel/Lumen 5.2 with apache 2.4

Tags: php, apache, laravel, lumen

**Environment details:**

- Windows 10
- PHP7
- Apache 2.4.

**The actions I took**

I installed Lumen into the htdocs folder using:

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/lumen blog
```

so now the file path to index.php is:

```
c:\Apache24\htdocs\blog\public\
```

This is the content of my routes.php:

```
$app->get('/', function () use ($app) {
    return $app->version();
});

$app->get( 'foo', function() {
    return "Hello World!";
} );
```

First I was not able to even access http://localhost/blog/public so I changed the line `$app->run();` in public/index.php code to `$app->run($app->make('request'));`

**The problem:**

Now I am unable to access http://localhost/blog/public/foo (with a response of 404)

**EDIT**

Based on Alexei's suggestion, I changed the config file and now http://localhost points to the '/' route, but I am still unable to access the http://localhost/foo

Thx for help ;)

Answer (score 2):

Do not make any changes in Laravel files. You should [point Apache to a `public` directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35843694/xampp-apache-rewrite-not-working) of Laravel project and restart it. After that use normal URLs like `http://localhost`.

Make these changes in Apache config:

```
DocumentRoot "c:\Apache24\htdocs\blog\public\"
<Directory "c:\Apache24\htdocs\blog\public\">
```

Comment: Hi, thx for the suggestion, I changed the config file an now http://localhost points to the '/' route, but I am still unable to access the http://localhost/foo

Comment: I award a +1 for the suggestion :)

Answer (score 0):

**In Apache - httpd.conf:**

- For the specified Directory change `AllowOverride` from *None* to *All*
- uncomment the line `LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so`