# How to improve url in Laravel?

Tags: linux, apache, laravel, server

I created my app on Homestead. Everything works fine there. But when I moved app to an external server I always have to include index.php after root path.

Example:

```
www.domain.com/index.php/contact
```

**How to I get rid of index.php to make my URL prettier?**

Application is located:

```
/var/www/
```

Public directory is renamed to html:

```
/var/www/html
```

PS. I'm using apache2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you already point your web server to public directory, your problem should be in your Apache conf.

Laravel comes out with `.htaccess` in `public/.htaccess` but you need to enable the mod rewrite in Apache for it to work

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

For the `.htaccess` to work, you need to set the `AllowOveride` directive in Apache conf

```
<Directory "/var/www/public">
AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Comment: Should I delete everything what is in public/.htacces and put those 3 lines of your code or add it inside?

Comment: Nope. That is supposed to be put in main conf so that .htaccess can be used to override the main configuration for this specific library

Comment: @user4938195: Did you enabled rewrite like the first command?

Comment: Yes. And inside /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-deafult.conf i pointed at public directory. DocumentRoot /var/www/public

Comment: Can you include this directive in that file? AllowOverride All

Comment: And run sudo service apache2 restart

Comment: @user4938195 : Try to put AllowOverride All right after DocumentRoot

Comment: Job for apache2.service failed. See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112909/discussion-between-user4938195-and-geckob).

Comment: Location of apache conf in case anyone forgets: /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

Answer (score 0):

You should [point Apache to a `public` directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35843694/xampp-apache-rewrite-not-working) which is inside Laravel directory. Restart Apache and you will be able to use normal URLs like `www.domain.com/contact`

You should use something like this when creating a virtual host:

```
DocumentRoot "/var/www/public"
<Directory "/var/www/public">
```

Comment: You renamed directory, but Laravel doesn't know about this. Try to configure Apache like I said, it's the right way to configure web server for Laravel project.