# Laravel Url Rewrite and avoid the public folder

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel

I've added the following to my public/.htaccess file in my laravel project.

```
#### Force lower case URL ####
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^[^A-Z]*[A-Z].*
RewriteRule ^ ${lc:%{REQUEST_URI}} [L,R=301]
```

It works as far as converting all upper-case characters to lower, however it reroutes the url to the public folder.

ie. /jobs gets rerouted to /public/jobs

Is there away to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't edit or add `.htaccess` file, edit `index.php` etc. What you should do is [point web server to a `public` directory instead of root one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35843694/xampp-apache-rewrite-not-working).

If you're using Apache, edit these lines in a virtual host block:

```
DocumentRoot "C:/projects/laravel/public"
<Directory "C:/projects/laravel/public">
```

Restart Apache and everything will work as expected.